# Update data in firebase object

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to update some data in an object in my firebase database, but have been unsuccessful so far.

I have been following the documentation to the point, but can't seem to get it right.. I'm fairly new to firebase, but this shouldn't be a huge problem.

[image]

My structure looks like this.

And this is how i have been trying to solve it:

```html
userRef.on("value", function(snapshot) {
 var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
 var key = user.uid;
   var getUser = snapshot.val();
   var userData = Object.keys(getUser);
 var userKey = userData[0];
 console.log(userKey);

 var db = firebase.database();
 var ref = db.ref("sofit-8ad52/profiles");
 console.log(key);
 var usersRef = ref.child(key);
 usersRef.set({
   userKey: {
     Username: "TEST",
   },
 });
});
```

Would love some help on this one.

Comment: What does `userRef` point to? Also: what is the problem when you run this code?

Comment: userRef is the child i want to access and edit

Comment: Please update your question to show how you initialize `userRef`. Also: what is the problem when you run this code?